# program which asks user to input 10 firstnames and ages, find oldest and youngest person,display their names and ages.program must use procedures

Tags: python

```
 File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\task-10.10.17.py", line 16, in generateInputs
    ages[counter]=validate(1,100,ages)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\task-10.10.17.py", line 3, in validate
    while number < min or number > max:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: #validate ages 
def validate(min,max,number):
    while number < min or number > max:
        message="Enter an age between "+ str(min)+ " and "+str(max)+" please:"
        number = int(input(message))
    return number
#get inputs
def generateInputs():
    nameList=[""]*10
    ages=[]*10
    for counter in range(0,10):
        print(counter+1,"enter the firstname please :")
        nameList[counter]=input()
        ages.append(counter)
        ages[counter]=int(input("enter the ages please :"))          
        ages[counter]=validate(1,100,ages)
    return nameList,ages

Comment: You want to put ` ` around your code, so it appears in a code block, so it's easier for us to read and you want to just edit your post not put it in the comments.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.